# Unity - Reading text off an echo'd php script into a string is not matching if statements

Tags: c#, php, string, unity-game-engine

So my project as of now is almost working:

It connects to facebook

It takes the Facebook ID and sends it to a script/iterator to handle connection

That script then sends off a concatenated string to a php url, which correctly checks my dataTable for an entry, and if not creates an entry

After that the php code echo's a text reply: OldUser/NewUserCreated/NewUserFailed

And here's where my problem starts:

the aim is to get the text from the echo, then check that string, if it works then unity moves on to the next scene and goes on, however when checking the string it fails for some reason, before I explain further here's my iterator that handles the connection:

```
IEnumerator Connect()
{
    //call databasequeries and get sDBConnect
    string sConnectPhp = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("DBConnector").GetComponent<DatabaseQueries>().sDBConnect;

    //now ready the url with the necessary code for php's get, and the FacebookID
    string url = sConnectPhp + "?UserID=" + sFacebookID;

    WWW wwwGet = new WWW(url);

    yield return wwwGet;

    string sTemp = wwwGet.text.ToString();

    if(wwwGet.error == null)
    {
        print (sTemp);

        if(sTemp == "OldUser")
        {
            //if successfully connected set to true
            print ("connectToDatabase: successful");
            bDatabaseConnected = true;
        }
        else if(sTemp == "NewUserCreated")
        {
            //if successfully connected set to true
            print ("connectToDatabase: successful");
            bDatabaseConnected = true;
        }
        else if(sTemp == "NewUserFailed")
        {
            //game connection has failed
            print ("connectToDatabase: failed");
            bDatabaseConnected = false;
            bConnectionFailed = true;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //game connection has failed
        print ("connectToDatabase: failed");
        bDatabaseConnected = false;
        bConnectionFailed = true;
    }
}
```

Now my problem is that sTemp is printing in the unity console: OldUser, and it's not matching my if else condition? I have tried copying wwwGet.text without ToString but that doesn't work either - printing shows OldUser, but it doesn't match the condition

My only guess is that I haven't used ToString correctly, but my searches have shown it being used for Decimal and currency conversion, and as said without toString sTemp is not matching, any ideas as to why it's not matching?

Comment: This might sound incredibly silly, but I have fallen for it: have you made sure there are no spaces before or after? I always wrap strings with quotation marks: print("'" + sTemp + "'"); Also, try comparing them like so: sTemp.ToLower().Equals("OldUser".ToLower())

Comment: Ok I'll give it a look, the workaround me and a friend came up with was to change the php echo to print out 0, then in unity convert that 0 to an int, then check that int, which is aggravating, but when I finish something else I'll check my scripts

Comment: No still no dice, changing the php to print with no caps, using the equals above doesn't run - it is checking but not matching, putting a space in the if/else (" olduser ") is a no, it seems like converting to an int is the only way which works - for now that's ok but saving a world state is impossible if I can't check the string it provides for errors.